# Can people use <a href=XX> tag in mantis?

Tags: mantis

I would like to show a hyperlink in some of fields on MantisBT, but I found out that if I use the `<a href=..>` tag, Mantis just shows the URL directly: Click here`

Mantis just shows the URL as a clickable link, not the text *Click here* as clickable.

Well the link works but it is just not that pretty. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

### Approach #1 hack the Mantis configuration

Put this in your **config_inc.php**. Adding 'a' to the list of valid tags should solve your problem:

```
   ############################
   # Mantis HTML Settings
   ############################

   # --- html tags -------------------

   # Set this flag to automatically convert www URLs and
   # email adresses into clickable links
   $g_html_make_links      = ON;

   # These are the valid html tags for multi-line fields (e.g. description)
   # do NOT include href or img tags here
   # do NOT include tags that have parameters (eg. <font face="arial">)
   $g_html_valid_tags      = 'p, li, ul, ol, br, pre, i, b, u, em';

   # These are the valid html tags for single line fields (e.g. issue summary).
   # do NOT include href or img tags here
   # do NOT include tags that have parameters (eg. <font face="arial">)
   $g_html_valid_tags_single_line      = 'i, b, u, em';
```

**Note:** that the config file advises against adding 'href' or 'img' tags (probably because these allow users to execute arbitrary javascript - opening the door to cross site scripting attacks)! But what does a stupid config file know, right?

### Approach #2 install a [BBCode](http://www.bbcode.org/) Plugin

On second thought, It's probably best to grab a plugin which implements the feature you want. I found two BBCode plugins that should work with the current Mantis versions (v1.1+, I think). Check out [this](https://github.com/jhron/BBCodeGeSHi/wiki/Description) or [this](https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/bbcode) one.

You should then be able to generate ordinary as well as named links like this:
`[url]http://www.bbcode.org/[/url]`
`[url=http://www.bbcode.org/]This be bbcode.org![/url]`

Comment: Hej Thanks a lot for your answer,I installed one of the plugin, it work, but the mantis add my host url in from the url after I submit the text. ex:[url=www.bbcode.org/]This be bbcode.org![/url] =>it show a clickable text on screen "This be bbcode.org!" but when you hover your curser on the link you can see the url inside is "mantis host url\www.the url you input. it feels like a configuration problem, but I am not sure. have you ever encountered this problem?